# how to get the product custom option in template file in the magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-options, magento-2.0.7

this is my code but when i echo   count ($_product->getOptions()) output show 0

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
    foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $options) {
    $optionType = $options->getType();
    $optionTitle = implode('_', explode(" ", $options->getTitle()));
    $options->getId();
```

how i get the product custom option in the magento 2

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the product options using this code,

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
```